# how to pass a variable to the ternary condition in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, ternary-operator

I tried this:

```
{{experience.current_work?"Present":{{experience.date_end | date:'MMM yyyy'}}}}
```

But this is wrong in ternary condition.How do I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're already within an expression (ie `{{...}}`) so you don't need to start a new one

```
{{experience.current_work ? "Present" : experience.date_end | date:'MMM yyyy'}}
```

or maybe this if you're worried about order of evaluation

```
{{experience.current_work ? "Present" : (experience.date_end | date:'MMM yyyy')}}
```

Comment: won't this try to filter whole instead of `date_end` only like for `present` also if it's current work ?

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi nope, at least not in the quick test I just did. I suppose you could wrap the *false* branch in parentheses just to be sure

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like few ways:

Call the function below when you need to check the condition:

```
$scope.CheckCurrentWork = function() {
    if ($scope.experience.current_work) {
        //Do as you want "Present"
    } else {
        //Do as you want 
        experience.date_end | date: 'MMM yyyy'
    }
}
```

OR

```
{{experience.current_work ? "Present" : experience.date_end | date:'MMM yyyy'}}
```

OR

If you want to apply your condition in any directive

```
<div ng-click="experience.current_work ?'Present' :  experience.date_end | date:'MMM yyyy'">
```